# Use of MERGE output as virtual table for an INSERT

Tags: t-sql, merge

With regards to this code (contrived, but based on a real example):

```
INSERT INTO ArchiveRecords 
(   
    DummyID,
    DummyName, 
    DummyCompany, 
    DummyActiveCode, 
    DummyDateOfSomething, 
    DummyValidFrom,
    DummyValidTo
)
SELECT
    MergeOutput.DummyID,
    MergeOutput.DummyName,
    MergeOutput.DummyCompany,
    MergeOutput.DummyActiveCode,
    MergeOutput.DummyDateOfSomething,
    MergeOutput.DummyValidFrom,
    MergeOutput.DummyValidTo
FROM
    (
        MERGE ArchiveRecords AS Trgt
        USING StagingRecords AS Src
            ON Trgt.DummyID = Src.DummyID

        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET DummyValidTo = GetDate()

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT 
                (   
                    DummyID, 
                    DummyName, 
                    DummyCompany, 
                    DummyActiveCode,
                    DummyDateOfSomething,
                    DummyValidFrom,
                    DummyValidTo
                )
                VALUES 
                    (
                        Src.DummyID,
                        Src.DummyName,
                        Src.DummyCompany,
                        Src.DummyActiveCode,
                        Src.DummyDateOfSomething,
                        Src.DummyValidFrom,
                        Src.DummyValidTo
                    )

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source AND Trgt.ValidTo IS NULL
            THEN UPDATE SET ValidTo = GetDate()

        OUTPUT
            $action AS act,
            Src.*  -- the whole table!
    ) AS MergeOutput
WHERE
    MergeOutput.act = 'UPDATE';
```

QUESTION: Is this a good idea to perform a MERGE inside a FROM clause?

I've stumbled across it in a new place I'm contracting at and have never seen this before.  As far as I can tell it will only affect about 200 rows at a time and no users are complaining about performance problems.

By instinct is that this is a bad idea, but I cannot quite explain the reason why (other than my own neophobia)

If anyone can think of solid reasons not to do this then I'd be interested in the reasons why.

Cheers,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make right decision you need to compare this code with alternative one which also do the same thing. As I can see, purpose of the code is to log records which were updated during `MERGE` operation on two tables. If so this is pretty solution because alternatively you need: a) to implement your own merge code to log modifications or b) to store a copy of table which is target table in `MERGE` and then compare it with modified table or c) update target table to store update flag and time and then log flagged records. All these solutions couldn't be done in one statement. Also `Src.*` in `OUTPUT` doesn't mean the whole table but only records affected by `MERGE`.

Comment: Thanks Serg. I think my reticence is because of the "active" action in the FROM clause. But as you say it does the job in 1 statement instead of 2.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that this is 'uncomfortable'. The reason of using such code is in filtering only `UPDATE` action of `MERGE`. Otherwise we are able to use `OUTPUT INTO` directly inside `MERGE`.